# Youtrack installed, but not reachable

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, services

I have installed YouTrack following the tutorial [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Install-YouTrack-JAR-as-Service-Linux.html).

With the command `service youtrack start` I can start the service and the Status Shows the following:

```
youtrack.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/youtrack; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-09-21 15:51:36 CEST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1892 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/youtrack stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 1957 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/youtrack start (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
```

But I can't reach the service. Also I am not very experinced with Linux, so there might be some simple mistake, which I don't see/recongnize.

```
youtrack.service - LSB: initscript for youtrack
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/youtrack; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-09-26 11:35:24 CEST; 2min 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5655 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/youtrack stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 5788 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/youtrack start (code=exited, status=0/SUCC

Sep 26 11:35:24 k003715vsa systemd[1]: Starting LSB: initscript for youtrack...
Sep 26 11:35:24 k003715vsa youtrack[5788]: Starting youtrack...
Sep 26 11:35:24 k003715vsa su[5789]: Successful su for youtrack by root
Sep 26 11:35:24 k003715vsa su[5789]: + ??? root:youtrack
Sep 26 11:35:24 k003715vsa su[5789]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for us
Sep 26 11:35:24 k003715vsa systemd[1]: Started LSB: initscript for youtrack.
```

Comment: How are you trying to "reach the service"? What makes you think this fails?

Comment: I tried it through a Webbrowser and I get a error, that this site is not reachable. Tried it also with the ip + port of the service.

Comment: Saying "I have installed YouTrack following the tutorial here" does NOT tell us what you actually did. There are multiple paths through the tutorial, multiple opportunities for you to mistype commands, misunderstand/ignore important messages, ..... sigh. In a terminal window type `pgrep youtrack;ps -fp1892,1957`

Comment: Using the command give me no values, just the Header of the table.